# How to save cookies and set stored cookies in rest kit next time application restart

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, cookies, restkit

I am developing one iPad application using rest kit After successfully  login the web service returns some cookies .

[[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookies] returns an array of cookies. I need to save this array of cookies and reuse after the application restart without call the web service.I tried KeyChain for save the cookies but that time application crashed.

```
KeychainItemWrapper *keychainItem = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"YourAppLogin" accessGroup:nil];
NSMutableArray *myArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSData *encodedData= [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:myArray];
NSString *encodedString=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:encodedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[keychainItem setObject:encodedString forKey:(__bridge id)(kSecValueData)];
NSString *decodedString=[keychainItem objectForKey:(__bridge id)(kSecValueData)];
NSData *decodedData= [decodedString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSMutableArray *decodedArray =[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:decodedData];
```

I follow above code to store cookies in keychain But the encoding String reruns Null values.

Then I tried userdefault method that time also my crashed shows the error." Attempt to set a non-property-list object as an NSUserDefaults value for key "

Someone help to save the cookies in properly and reuse with rest kit after application restart

Comment: Why are the cookies not automatically saved? Why do you need to save and restore them?

Comment: @Wain cookies are automatically saved when i will do the online login for sync data.If i will stop the application after sync the data the login is doing based on the data in my local db i am not calling the web url api.That time i did not get the response cookies i need response cookies in rest kit call some another urls.So i want to use the response cookies  return by the api in initial login.